# How to ask for user mail

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uialertview, user-experience

I can't find any example of apps asking for user email adress. I think of a UIAlertView with a textfield to fill... But I can't find this kind of thing.

Is there a guideline for this prupose ?
Is there a dedicated UI element that could help ?

If I could avoid having to create a whole view stacked in navigation controller it would be better

Thanks again for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe **presentModalViewController:animated:** method of UIViewController class will be a better solution. It takes an arbitrary controller and shows its view. You can select an animation type and other options.

UIAlertView purpose is to show alerts, but not to handle user input. But it depends on the concrete task and a lot of other factors.

Comment: It seems to be the best way to create a custom view for this purpose. Thanks for your help